# Check if something is Base64 encoded

Tags: regex, node.js, base64, decode, encode

I want to check if a string is Base64 encoded or not.

Here is my attempt:

```js
var base64Rejex = new RegExp(
    /([A-Za-z0-9+\/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+\/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+\/]{2}==$)/
)

var base64Data = 'RULES'
var isBase64Valid = base64Rejex.test(base64Data) // base64Data is the base64 string

if (isBase64Valid) {
    // True if in Base64 format
    console.log('It is base64')
    var data = new Buffer(base64Data, 'base64').toString('ascii')
    console.log('THIS IS IS ' + data)
} else {
    // False if not in Base64 format
    console.log('it is not in base64')
}
```

Even though the above string is *not* Base64 encoded, my code always outputs that it is.

How can I check if a string is Base64 encoded or not? Is there something I need to modify in my regex?

Comment: From my experience, I know it is sometimes impossible to tell a Base64 string from a non-Base64 since final `==` are not always required. Some regular strings may be identified as Base64.

Comment: @stribizhev - Thanks for your response.So do i have to restrict the length of the string to be more than 5 and check?

Comment: If you know your Base64 data cannot be just 4 symbol long (and these are the most frequent false positives) - yes.

Comment: A Base64 string must have a length equivalent to a multiple of 4, padded with 0, 1 or 2 `=` characters.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below, where `str` is the string you want to check.

```js
Buffer.from(str, 'base64').toString('base64') === str
```